# wrting @ in javascript in mvc razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having a regex expresssion in javascript in a mvc razor page. I cannot use @ in the regex as it thrown a error due to razor syntax.
Below is my code. It show a red squiggle line under @ as it is razor syntax keyword.

```
 if(!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(dirEmail2)){
                        return false;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem with me please use double @@ like.

```
      function validateEmail(email) {
        var re =  /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@@"]+)*)|(".+"))@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
```